# Is there a way to measure C# function execution time from an attribute?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes, aop, interception

I'm looking to publish custom performance counters for certain important function calls in the system.  I'd like to continously monitor these performance counters in a production environment.

Is there a way for me to mark certain functions with a custom attribute that could measure the time it took to execute given function?  I'd like to avoid injecting custom code and thus polluting business-related functions with monitoring code.

How can a code from an attribute track the time it took for function to execute?

Please do not suggest use of a Profiler.  I'm not looking to debug or benchmark performance.  But simply wanting to track it in on a production 24/7 basis.

Comment: Is it for a web application (ASP.NET) or Desktop (WinForms, WPF)?

Comment: or Windows services... this is to monitor performance of certain framework-level code that can be used by various consumers

Comment: Since you will change (you need to) your code to add the attribute, would it be alright for you if you put your *code* into an *Action* or *Func* and thus wrap the execution into a *measurement function*? This is how i did it for a project i was working for. It is not so elegant as using attributes though, but it doesn't need any (complex) dependencies.

Comment: was hoping to make it seamless.  But yes, your way would be an alternative I suppose

Comment: @Igorek Many DI containers allows you to do it in a really seamless manner. See the update in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you need some code to execute your function and analyze your `attribute` so it will know that it needs to execute something (e.g. execution time measurement, in your case) before and after your function - it could be using the [Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) design pattern, [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), [Proxy object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and so on.

As you tagged, it is an *aspect-programming* issue and you can take advantage of [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.net/) third-party, for example, in order to achieve it.

Take a look at this specific page about Performance Counters using PostSharp, it is indeed uses Attributes: http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/performance

To elaborate a little on @pasty's comment, you can intercept your methods invocations with [Interception using Unity DI Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466%28v=pandp.30%29.aspx), it is indeed requires more code to write, here is a simple sample flow chart of the Unity interception feature:

[image: shows the objects that are involved with interception behaviors in this example]

Note to step **3**, where a **proxy object** is actually returned to the client and thanks to that, the interception behavior is achieved.

Comment: can I use the free version of Postsharp for this?

Comment: From PostSharp: _Diagnostics and Threading Pattern Libraries, plus advanced features not found in PostSharp Express_ but you can try it for 45 days no-charge.

Comment: As an alternative to PostSharp you could have a look at [Microsoft's Patterns & Practices Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn170416.aspx) - it is possible to intercept the execution of a method using an attribute, but you need to implement it by yourself.

Comment: I think the PostSharp link doesn't exists anymore. However, there's a blog post addressing this topic: http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Microsoft-Application-Insights-adding-custom-metrics-without-modifying-your-source-code